# Skipping columns which loading data into an external table

Tags: oracle, external-tables

This is the external table I created:

```
CREATE TABLE emp_load 
(
  "ESN_NO" VARCHAR2 (200), 
  "MAKER" VARCHAR2 (30), 
  "HANDSET" VARCHAR2 (20), 
  "MODEL_NO" VARCHAR2 (20), 
  "OMH_TTSL_FLAG" VARCHAR2 (10), 
  "OFFER" VARCHAR2 (100), 
  "STATUS" VARCHAR2 (20), 
  "STATUS_UPDATED_DATE" DATE
) ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER DEFAULT DIRECTORY "EXT_TAB_DIR" ACCESS PARAMETERS (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE skip 1
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    missing FIELD VALUES are NULL
    ) LOCATION ('BAU.csv')
) ;
```

The sample contents of `BAU.csv` file

```
ESN No          Make    Model   RI_value
A10000428A5348  Lava    C180    OFFER14
A10000428A5349  Lava    C180    OFFER14
A10000428A534A  Lava    C180    OFFER14
A10000428A534B  Lava    C180    OFFER14
```

It works fine but the data isn't appearing in the columns as I need; I want the column `handset` to be empty, but currently the `model` value from the file  gets loaded into the `handset` column. So I currently get:

```
ESN_NO          MAKER  HANDSET  MODEL_NO  OMH_TTSL_FLAG  OFFER  STATUS  STATUS_UPDATED_DATE  
A10000428A5348  Lava   C180     OFFER14                                                      
A10000428A5349  Lava   C180     OFFER14                                                      
A10000428A534A  Lava   C180     OFFER14                                                      
A10000428A534B  Lava   C180     OFFER14
```

I want the `handset` column to be skipped and the `model` to be inserted in `model_no`; and `omh_ttsl_flag` should be skipped and the `ri_value` from the file should be inserted in `offer`. So what I want to end up with is:

```
ESN_NO          MAKER  HANDSET  MODEL_NO  OMH_TTSL_FLAG  OFFER    STATUS  STATUS_UPDATED_DATE  
A10000428A5348  Lava            C180                     OFFER14                               
A10000428A5349  Lava            C180                     OFFER14                               
A10000428A534A  Lava            C180                     OFFER14                               
A10000428A534B  Lava            C180                     OFFER14
```

How can I skip over those columns while loading the data into the external table?

Comment: @PravinS how did u edit it

Comment: Presumably you do need the table to have that structure, with all those columns and in that order; you can't create the table with just the four columns that map to your file values? Or have all the columns you're leaving blank after the ones you are getting from the file?

Comment: Also please check I've interpreted what you currently have and what you want correctly, and that the edit I made to your question is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by specifying the fields in the file as part of the `fields` clause, and specifying the ones that don't appear with [the `column transforms` clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_params.htm#i1012621), e.g:

```
COLUMN TRANSFORMS ("HANDSET" FROM NULL, "OMH_TTSL_FLAG" FROM NULL)
```

So your statement becomes:

```
CREATE TABLE emp_load 
(
  "ESN_NO" VARCHAR2 (200), 
  "MAKER" VARCHAR2 (30), 
  "HANDSET" VARCHAR2 (20), 
  "MODEL_NO" VARCHAR2 (20), 
  "OMH_TTSL_FLAG" VARCHAR2 (10), 
  "OFFER" VARCHAR2 (100), 
  "STATUS" VARCHAR2 (20), 
  "STATUS_UPDATED_DATE" DATE
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
(
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER DEFAULT DIRECTORY "EXT_TAB_DIR" ACCESS PARAMETERS
  (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE skip 1
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    (
      "ESN_NO" CHAR (200), 
      "MAKER" CHAR (30), 
      "MODEL_NO" CHAR (20), 
      "OFFER" CHAR (100)
    )
    COLUMN TRANSFORMS
    (
      "HANDSET" FROM NULL,
      "OMH_TTSL_FLAG" FROM NULL,
      "STATUS" FROM NULL,
      "STATUS_UPDATED_DATE" FROM NULL
    )
  )
  LOCATION ('BAU.csv')
) ;
```

I've included the other two columns, which isn't necessary but helps document what you expect to see.

With your sample data translated to CSV that loads as:

```
set sqlformat ansiconsole
column esn_no format a20
select * from emp_load;

ESN_NO          MAKER  HANDSET  MODEL_NO  OMH_TTSL_FLAG  OFFER    STATUS  STATUS_UPDATED_DATE  
A10000428A5348  Lava            C180                     OFFER14                               
A10000428A5349  Lava            C180                     OFFER14                               
A10000428A534A  Lava            C180                     OFFER14                               
A10000428A534B  Lava            C180                     OFFER14
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into emp_load (ESN_NO,MAKER,MODEL_NO,OFFER)
values ('A10000428A5348','Lava','Lava','OFFER14)
```

the default is null , so all other columns will received null

Comment: That is a external table , i want to skip some columns so i need to change it in the create statement, i need those changes